# Problem with Intel Macook restarting

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, crash, kernel-panic

My intel MacBook 2020 with Sonoma OS has been restarting with these logs

```
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xfffffff0289d03e0): ANS2 Recoverable Panic - assert failed: [14533]:apcie0[0]: 4/4 links are down linksts=0xab000000 pcielint=0x00007000, ltssm=0x00(DETECT_QUIET) - power(13)
assert failed: [14533]:apcie0[0]: 4/4 links are down linksts=0xab000000 pcielint=0x00007000, ltssm=0x00(DETECT_QUIET)
RTKit: RTKit-2413.1.1.release - Client: t8012.release-AppleStorageProcessorANS2-1306~4987~1306~4987
!UUID: fc11a0f3-029a-32fb-86ea-7573dc1cdeab
Time: 0x000000008c01a921

Faulting task  13 Call Stack: 0x0000000000015514 0x0000000000014e90 0x0000000000014c94 0x00000000000171d0 0x000000000001c6e4 0x000000000001c718 0x000000000010ff90 0x000000000000e838 0x000000000000933c 0x000000000000860c 0x000000000001473c 0x00000000000146e4 0x0000000000014480 0x000000000000cb84 000000000000000000

Marin ASC Async error info: 
l2c_err_sts 0x10001bfc00000000, l2c_err_adr 000000000000000000, l2c_err_inf 000000000000000000
lsu_err_sts 000000000000000000, fed_err_sts 000000000000000000, mmu_err_sts 000000000000000000
dpc_err_sts 000000000000000000

Mailbox (0): (0)
  Inbox  AKF_KIC_INBOX_CTRL = 0x00020001, AKF_KIC_MAILBOX_SET = 0x00000101
  Outbox AKF_AP_OUTBOX_CTRL = 0x00020001, AKF_AP_MAILBOX_SET  = 0x00000000

    dir   endpoint      timestamp           msg
    ====  ============  ==================  ==================
    [RX]   ioreporting  0x000000000603e0e4  0x0080000000000000
    [TX]   ioreporting  0x000000000603e138  0x0080000000000000
    [RX]   ioreporting  0x000000000603eb20  0x0080000000000000
    [TX]   ioreporting  0x000000000603eba4  0x0080000000000000
    [RX]   ioreporting  0x000000000603f980  0x0080000000000000
    [TX]   ioreporting  0x000000000603f9e0  0x0080000000000000
    [RX]   ioreporting  0x0000000006040ae4  0x0080000000000000
    [TX]   ioreporting  0x0000000006040b60  0x0080000000000000
    [RX]   ioreporting  0x000000000604283c  0x0080000000000000
    [TX]   ioreporting  0x000000000604288c  0x0080000000000000
    [RX]   ioreporting  0x0000000006043214  0x0080000000000000
    [TX]   ioreporting  0x000000000604328c  0x0080000000000000
    [RX]   ioreporting  0x00000000060440e4  0x0080000000000000
    [TX]   ioreporting  0x0000000006044138  0x0080000000000000
    [RX]   ioreporting  0x0000000006045e28  0x0080000000000000
    [TX]    management  0x0000000006056140  0x0070000000000020
    [RX]    management  0x0000000006056c94  0x00b0000000000020
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000006056d2c  0x0080000080000010
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000006056d40  0x0010400000000000
    [RX]        syslog  0x00000000060573e4  0x0010400806b98000
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000006057600  0x0050000000000000
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000006057608  0x0050000000000001
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000006057618  0x0050000000000002
    [TX]    management  0x000000000605762c  0x00b0000000000020
    [RX]        syslog  0x00000000060578d8  0x0050000000000000
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000006057918  0x0050000000000001
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000006057960  0x0050000000000002
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000006158448  0x0050000000000003
    [TX]        syslog  0x000000000615850c  0x0050000000000004
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000006158830  0x0050000000000003
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000006158884  0x0050000000000004
    [TX]        syslog  0x00000000061589c0  0x0050000000000005
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000006158a9c  0x0050000000000006
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000006158b1c  0x0050000000000007
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000006158b6c  0x0050000000000008
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000006158bd4  0x0050000000000009
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000006158c14  0x005000000000000a
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000006158c70  0x005000000000000b
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000006158cc4  0x005000000000000c
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000006158d14  0x005000000000000d
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000006158e20  0x0050000000000005
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000006158e80  0x0050000000000006
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000006158ee4  0x0050000000000007
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000006158f30  0x0050000000000008
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000006158f90  0x0050000000000009
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000006158fd0  0x005000000000000a
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000006159024  0x005000000000000b
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000006159070  0x005000000000000c
    [RX]        syslog  0x00000000061590c4  0x005000000000000d
    [TX]        syslog  0x000000000615914c  0x005000000000000e
    [RX]        syslog  0x00000000061594ac  0x005000000000000e
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000006220c48  0x005000000000000f
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000006220cd8  0x0050000000000000
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000006220d5c  0x0050000000000001
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000006220de0  0x0050000000000002
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000006220e7c  0x0050000000000003
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000006220f5c  0x0050000000000004
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000006221080  0x005000000000000f
    [RX]        syslog  0x00000000062210d8  0x0050000000000000
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000006221124  0x0050000000000001
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000006221158  0x0050000000000002
    [RX]        syslog  0x00000000062211b4  0x0050000000000003
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000006221208  0x0050000000000004
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000006af95ec  0x0050000000000005
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000006af98f4  0x0050000000000005
    [TX]        syslog  0x00000000074d3fb0  0x0050000000000006
    [RX]        syslog  0x00000000074d42ac  0x0050000000000006
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000008ddf518  0x0050000000000007
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000008ddf908  0x0050000000000007
    [RX]    management  0x0000000008de4aac  0x0050002000000002
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000008de835c  0x0050000000000008
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000008de83ac  0x0050000000000009
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000008de848c  0x005000000000000a
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000008de8698  0x0050000000000008
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000008de8708  0x0050000000000009
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000008de8744  0x005000000000000a
    [TX]        syslog  0x000000000adeeba4  0x005000000000000b
    [RX]        syslog  0x000000000adef634  0x005000000000000b
    [TX]        syslog  0x000000000c2f7bf4  0x005000000000000c
    [RX]        syslog  0x000000000c2f83fc  0x005000000000000c
    [TX]        syslog  0x000000000e993484  0x005000000000000d
    [RX]        syslog  0x000000000e993880  0x005000000000000d
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000010bd34b4  0x005000000000000e
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000010bd35d0  0x005000000000000f
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000010bd3f94  0x005000000000000e
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000010bd4134  0x005000000000000f
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000029333e84  0x0050000000000000
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000029333f94  0x0050000000000001
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000029334cb4  0x0050000000000000
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000029335010  0x0050000000000001
    [TX]        syslog  0x00000000a8f886c0  0x0050000000000002
    [RX]        syslog  0x00000000a8f88e14  0x0050000000000002
    [TX]        syslog  0x00000000a9443818  0x0050000000000003
    [RX]        syslog  0x00000000a9444504  0x0050000000000003
    [RX]    management  0x00000000a9447fcc  0x00b0000000000201
    [TX]    management  0x00000000a944817c  0x00b0000000000201
    [RX]    management  0x00000000a944932c  0x0060000000000201
    [TX]    management  0x000000000011f294  0x00100000000c000c
    [RX]    management  0x0000000000141028  0x00200000000c000c
    [TX]    management  0x0000000000141108  0x008000000000001f
    [RX]    management  0x000000000015698c  0x008000000000001f
    [TX]    management  0x00000000001569b0  0x0088000100000003
    [RX]    management  0x0000000000158a20  0x0088000100000003
    [TX]        user02  0x0000000000158ec4  0x0401000000000000
    [RX]        user02  0x000000000015c3dc  0x0403000000000101
    [RX]        user02  0x000000000015c500  0x0205000000000000
    [TX]        user02  0x000000000015cffc  0x0405000000000100
    [TX]        user02  0x000000000015d050  0x0305000000000000
    [RX]        user02  0x000000000015e4cc  0x0206000000000000
    [TX]        user02  0x000000000015e4e0  0x0306000000000000
    [RX]        user02  0x0000000000168c40  0x0406000000000100
    [TX]    management  0x0000000000322e5c  0x0070000000000020
    [RX]    management  0x0000000000328738  0x00b0000000000020
    [TX]        syslog  0x000000000032886c  0x0050000000000000
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000000328874  0x0050000000000001
    [TX]        syslog  0x000000000032887c  0x0050000000000002
    [TX]    management  0x00000000003288d8  0x00b0000000000020
    [RX]        syslog  0x000000000032a2a8  0x0050000000000000
    [RX]        syslog  0x000000000032a310  0x0050000000000001
    [RX]        syslog  0x000000000032a368  0x0050000000000002
    [TX]        syslog  0x000000000032e34c  0x0050000000000003
    [TX]        syslog  0x000000000032e428  0x0050000000000004
    [RX]        syslog  0x00000000003324b4  0x0050000000000003
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000000332550  0x0050000000000004
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000000cee398  0x0050000000000005
    [TX]        syslog  0x0000000000cee494  0x0050000000000006
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000000cef1a8  0x0050000000000005
    [RX]        syslog  0x0000000000cef708  0x0050000000000006
RTKit Task List:
   name                    | pri     | stack use | status     | resource | warning
 0 rtk_ep_work             | 057     |   816/2048  | SEMWAIT    | 0x18ade0 | 
      0x000000000011af74 0x000000000000cf64 0x00000000000157f4 0x000000000000cb84

 1 smc_mbox_work_loop      | 016     |   904/4096  | SEMWAIT    | 0x189700 | 
      0x000000000000c29c 0x000000000000cf64 0x00000000000157f4 0x000000000000cb84

 2 Null                    | 015     |   736/4096  | SEMWAIT    | 0x185330 | 
      0x000000000011af74 0x000000000011e928 0x000000000011e994 0x000000000003cbb0 0x000000000000cb84

 3 Update                  | 015     |  1904/4096  | SEMWAIT    | 0x183de0 | 
      0x000000000011af74 0x000000000011e62c 0x0000000000099fd4 0x000000000003cbb0 0x000000000000cb84

 4 GC                      | 015     |  1744/4096  | SEMWAIT    | 0x182ac0 | 
      0x000000000000c29c 0x000000000011e62c 0x0000000000096710 0x000000000003cbb0 0x000000000000cb84

 5 BG                      | 015     |  2240/4096  | SEMWAIT    | 0x1813f0 | 
      0x000000000011af74 0x000000000011e62c 0x0000000000054be0 0x000000000003cbb0 0x000000000000cb84

 6 Push                    | 015     |  1792/4096  | SEMWAIT    | 0x1801d0 | 
      0x000000000011af74 0x000000000011e62c 0x00000000000a17e4 0x000000000003cbb0 0x000000000000cb84

 7 Raid                    | 015     |  1328/4096  | SEMWAIT    | 0x17ed00 | 
      0x000000000000c29c 0x000000000011e62c 0x00000000000eedac 0x000000000003cbb0 0x000000000000cb84

 8 PreNand                 | 015     |   944/4096  | SEMWAIT    | 0xffffffff620ffea0 | 
      0x000000000011af74 0x000000000011e62c 0x000000000003e8a0 0x000000000003cbb0 0x000000000000cb84

 9 DataXfer                | 015     |   592/4096  | SEMWAIT    | 0xffffffff620feed0 | 
      0x000000000011af74 0x000000000011e62c 0x00000000000e0c34 0x000000000003cbb0 0x000000000000cb84

10 PostNand                | 015     |   816/4096  | SEMWAIT    | 0xffffffff620fde50 | 
      0x000000000000c29c 0x000000000011e62c 0x00000000001222f0 0x000000000003cbb0 0x000000000000cb84

11 Cmd                     | 015     |  1952/8192  | SEMWAIT    | 0xffffffff620fca50 | 
      0x000000000000c29c 0x000000000011e62c 0x000000000006d4b0 0x000000000011cba8 0x000000000003cbb0 0x000000000000cb84

12 Timer                   | 015     |   880/4096  | SEMWAIT    | 0xffffffff620fa6a0 | 
      0x000000000000c29c 0x000000000011e62c 0x00000000000574cc 0x000000000003cbb0 0x000000000000cb84

13 power                   | 060     |  1312/4096  | RUNNABLE   | 0 | [Faulting task]

14 System Thread           | 015     |  1136/4096  | SUSPENDED  | 0 | 
      0x000000000000c29c 0x0000000000009b8c

15 aspcore timer tick      | 061     |   320/4096  | SEMWAIT    | 0xffffffff620f7c50 | 
      0x000000000000c29c 0x000000000003ceb8 0x000000000000cb84


APCIE 0
  Link 0: Present, link down, ltssm 0x00(DETECT_QUIET), VID/DID 0x106b/0x2004, linksts 0xab000000, pcielint 0x00007000
    L-state entries: [L0] 146989 [L1.0] 232378 [L1.1] 124 [L1.2] 85300 
  Link 1: Present, link down, ltssm 0x00(DETECT_QUIET), VID/DID 0x106b/0x2004, linksts 0xab000000, pcielint 0x00007000
    L-state entries: [L0] 147037 [L1.0] 232508 [L1.1] 7 [L1.2] 85464 
  Link 2: Present, link down, ltssm 0x00(DETECT_QUIET), VID/DID 0x106b/0x2004, linksts 0xab000000, pcielint 0x00007000
    L-state entries: [L0] 141898 [L1.0] 234242 [L1.1] 7 [L1.2] 92337 
  Link 3: Present, link down, ltssm 0x00(DETECT_QUIET), VID/DID 0x106b/0x2004, linksts 0xab000000, pcielint 0x00007000
    L-state entries: [L0] 141712 [L1.0] 234634 [L1.1] 7 [L1.2] 92915 

APCIE 1
  Link 0: Unknown, link disabled
  Link 1: Unknown, link disabled
  Link 2: Unknown, link disabled
  Link 3: Unknown, link disabled

NVME 0
  CC: 0x00470001, CSTS: 0x00000001
  Admin SQ: 0x806bec000, size: 65, tail/head: 4/4
  Admin CQ: 0x806be4000, size: 65, tail/head: 4/4
  I/O SQ  : 0x806bf0000, size: 65, tail/head: 44/44
  I/O CQ  : 0x806be8000, size: 65, tail/head: 44/44

NVME 1
  CC: 0x00470001, CSTS: 0x00000001
  Admin SQ: 0x000010000, size: 129, tail/head: 4/4
  Admin CQ: 0x00000c000, size: 129, tail/head: 4/4
  I/O SQ  : 0x000018000, size: 129, tail/head: 45/45
  I/O CQ  : 0x00000d000, size: 129, tail/head: 45/45
 
Nand_Desc : 0x31931d
Unmasked HWINTMON [0] 0xe00
Unmasked HWINTMON [1] 0x0
Unmasked HWINTMON [2] 0x0
Unmasked HWINTMON [3] 0x0
     
ASP summary:
HR=0x378ac961 HW=0xe5966e50 CW=0x168242f NR=0x265a1ca9 NW=0x9b7f7760 M=0 Bu=494 Bi=186 D=0,0 V=355400KB BF=1, 3 L=0 Q=0,1 E=0xad46 debugTrigger=0
KE=0x1 KY=0x0 KD=0x0 KT=0x232d4 LA=0x8ade2076 KW=0xfffe KQ=1
0-0x8ade1850 1-0x86c95068 2-0xd7037ca 3-0x8abfc16f 4-0x86dbee3c 5-0x86c8bff3 6-0x8ade2028 7-0x8ac23e82 8-0x8addcae4 9-0x8addcb16 10-0x8abfb311 
KLA=0x8ade2076 LSSTS=0x8abfb40b DIFF=0x1e6c6b Plf=0x0 SPw=0x0 SPtwc=0x0
FBB=0x12b GBB=0x0 RXBD=0x0 RB=0x0 PROB=0x0
UB=0x37 UECC=0x0 IUECC=0x0 PFAIL=0x0 EFAIL=0x0 CPF=0x0 CRF=0x0 RRFH=0x0 RRFI=0x0 E2EF=0x0
FWU 0x8 
Intr cycles: min=0xc5c max=0xc5e ave=0xc5c 
User cycles: min=0x3a max=0x40 ave=0x3b 
F[0]=43 F[1]=0 F[2]=0 F[3]=0 F[4]=9 F[5]=24 F[6]=0 F[7]=218 F[8]=2 F[9]=0 F[10]=1 F[11]=0 F[12]=494 F[13]=186 F[14]=8 F[15]=1 F[16]=0 F[17]=7 F[18]=5 F[19]=8 
B: GM=0 S=7

MSP FW Version: msp_core_toshiba_itlc_3d_g4_2p_256-75.35.0


SegQs.pendingUnitCompleteQ
 [0]:FF54, FF54, 0
 [1]:FF55, FF55, 0
 [2]:FF56, FF56, 0
 [3]:FF57, FF57, 0
 [4]:FF58, FF58, 0
 [5]:FF59, FF59, 0
 [6]:FF5A, FF5A, 0
 [7]:FF5B, FF5B, 0
 [8]:FF5C, FF5C, 0
 [9]:FF5D, FF5D, 0
 [10]:FF5E, FF5E, 0
 [11]:FF5F, FF5F, 0
 [12]:FF60, FF60, 0
 [13]:FF61, FF61, 0
 [14]:FF62, FF62, 0
 [15]:FF63, FF63, 0
 [16]:FF64, FF64, 0
 [17]:FF65, FF65, 0
 [18]:FF66, FF66, 0
 [19]:FF67, FF67, 0
SegQs.cache_FS_CleanQ
 [0]:4184, 409D, 65792
SegQs.cacheDirtyQ
 [0]:FF69, FF69, 0
 [1]:40CF, 4172, 512
SegQs.cachePendQ
 [0]:FF6B, FF6B, 0
 [1]:FF6C, FF6C, 0
 [2]:FF6D, FF6D, 0
 [3]:FF6E, FF6E, 0
SegQs.prefetchActiveQ
 [0]:4632, 468D, 4096
SegQs.prefetchFreeQ
 [0]:FF70, FF70, 0
SegQs.clogLoadUpdateQ
 [0]:FF71, FF71, 0
SegQs.clogPortableQ
 [0]:FF72, FF72, 0
SegQs.clogPortableDoneQ
 [0]:FF73, FF73, 0
SegQs.stolenQ
 [0]:FF74, FF74, 0
SegQs.gcNoBlog
 [0]:FF75, FF75, 0
SegQs.raidSaveSegQ
 [0]:FF76, FF76, 0
SegQs.raidInBandParityWipQ
 [0]:FF77, FF77, 0
SegQs.parityGenerateQ
 [0]:FF78, FF78, 0
BP:
 Mode Estimates:
    0 | SLC estimate 1256, MLC/TLC estimate 1256
    1 | SLC estimate 2816, MLC/TLC estimate 1256
    2 | SLC estimate 1256, MLC/TLC estimate 1256
     L estimate 4000

BP:
 Budgeting:
    0 | Budget 2147483647 Adjust 0
    1 | Budget 2147483647 Adjust 0
    2 | Budget 2147483647 Adjust 0
    3 | Budget 2147483647 Adjust 0
    4 | Budget 2147483647 Adjust 0

Wos:
  mLH=0x35 hIM=0x16 hBIM=0x2d lRM=0x2329f lWP=0x3 hP=0x57e40 hE=0x0 hN=0x0 sSE=0x0 sSN=0x0 bET1=0x0
lWM[0]=0x2322d lWM[1]=0x23129 lWM[2]=0x23127 lWM[3]=0x23083   td=0x0 hXW=0x0 FScc=0x101 FSec=0x0 FStc=0x103 FSus=0x1 Cds=0xc ES=0x0 ePFM=0x0 FSW=0 uFS=1 uDS=1 s=1

Thermal Throttle Levels:  read: 0, prog: 0, comm: 0

Fences:
  ..... 
NVRAM value string [40A0DDD2-77F8-4392-B4A3-1E7304206516:storage-prev-assert]:[0x656d9a9f,14533,0,0,4]
NVRAM value string [40A0DDD2-77F8-4392-B4A3-1E7304206516:storage-prev-assert-stored]:[0x656d9a9f,0]
Sleep Count: 189
Wake Count:  186
Duty Cycle:  150

Buf:
  mgrCC: fC=0x211 w=0x0 hW=0x2 mE=0x200 bI=0x1eae9 E->s=0x27b E->e=0x48c
  mgrCC ranges:  0{0x1eae9,0x1ef75}  1{0xffffffff,0xffffffff}  
  mgrGP: fC=0x1bc0 w=0x0 hW=0x3 mE=0x34ec bI=0x19511 E->s=0x0 E->e=0x1bc0
  mgrGP ranges:  0{0x19511,0x1b0d1}  1{0xffffffff,0xffffffff}  
  mgrGC: fC=0x0 w=0x0 hW=0x5 mE=0x1e1 bI=0x1ad11 E->s=0xffff E->e=0xffff
  mgrGC ranges:  0{0xffffffff,0xffffffff}  1{0xffffffff,0xffffffff}  
Sleep Count: 189
Wake Count:  186
Duty Cycle:  150

RTBuddy(AP): Debug info:
_iopStatus = 0x8
_powerStateChangeLocked = false
Mailbox Status:
IDLE_STATUS: 0x00000028
MAILBOX_SET: 0x00000000
MAILBOX_CLR: 0x00000000
INBOX_CTRL: 0x00020001
OUTBOX_CTRL: 0x00021101
AP->IOP Mailbox Log:
Timestamp          | Dir  | Message
0x0000000008ddf6a0 | [RX] | 0x0050000000000007 0x0010780000000002
0x0000000008ddf89c | [TX] | 0x0050000000000007 0x0000000000000002
0x0000000008de4a48 | [TX] | 0x0050002000000002 000000000000000000
0x0000000008de84bc | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000000008de84cc | [RX] | 0x0050000000000008 0x00308b0000000002
0x0000000008de84d4 | [RX] | 0x0050000000000009 0x00209b0000000002
0x0000000008de84d8 | [RX] | 0x005000000000000a 0x0010ab0000000002
0x0000000008de867c | [TX] | 0x0050000000000008 0x0000000000000002
0x0000000008de86d8 | [TX] | 0x0050000000000009 0x0000000000000002
0x0000000008de8730 | [TX] | 0x005000000000000a 0x0000000000000002
0x000000000adeebf4 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x000000000adeec40 | [RX] | 0x005000000000000b 0x0010bc0000000002
0x000000000adef5bc | [TX] | 0x005000000000000b 0x0000000000000002
0x000000000c2f7c48 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x000000000c2f7c88 | [RX] | 0x005000000000000c 0x0010cd0000000002
0x000000000c2f8370 | [TX] | 0x005000000000000c 0x0000000000000002
0x000000000e9934c0 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x000000000e993500 | [RX] | 0x005000000000000d 0x0010010000000002
0x000000000e993808 | [TX] | 0x005000000000000d 0x0000000000000002
0x0000000010bd384c | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000000010bd3898 | [RX] | 0x005000000000000e 0x0020020000000002
0x0000000010bd38a8 | [RX] | 0x005000000000000f 0x0010120000000002
0x0000000010bd3f4c | [TX] | 0x005000000000000e 0x0000000000000002
0x0000000010bd4120 | [TX] | 0x005000000000000f 0x0000000000000002
0x0000000029333fac | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000000029334014 | [RX] | 0x0050000000000000 0x0020020000000002
0x0000000029334030 | [RX] | 0x0050000000000001 0x0010120000000002
0x0000000029334c84 | [TX] | 0x0050000000000000 0x0000000000000002
0x0000000029335000 | [TX] | 0x0050000000000001 0x0000000000000002
0x00000000a8f889c4 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x00000000a8f889f0 | [RX] | 0x0050000000000002 0x0010010000000002
0x00000000a8f88da4 | [TX] | 0x0050000000000002 0x0000000000000002
0x00000000a9443bb4 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x00000000a9443bfc | [RX] | 0x0050000000000003 0x0010120000000002
0x00000000a9444490 | [TX] | 0x0050000000000003 0x0000000000000002
0x00000000a9447fb4 | [TX] | 0x00b0000000000201 000000000000000000
0x00000000a94482d8 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x00000000a9448314 | [RX] | 0x00b0000000000201 0x0010230000000000
0x00000000a9449318 | [TX] | 0x0060000000000201 000000000000000000
0x00000000a9469200 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x00000000a9469248 | [RX] | 0x0070000000000201 0x0010340000000000
0x00000000a95c1948 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x00000000a95c198c | [RX] | 0x00100000000c000c 0x0010010000000000
0x00000000a95e3638 | [TX] | 0x00200000000c000c 000000000000000000
0x00000000a95e37f4 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x00000000a95e3828 | [RX] | 0x008000000000001f 0x0010120000000000
0x00000000a95f8fa8 | [TX] | 0x008000000000001f 000000000000000000
0x00000000a95f9054 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x00000000a95f9080 | [RX] | 0x0088000100000003 0x0010230000000000
0x00000000a95fb040 | [TX] | 0x0088000100000003 000000000000000000
0x00000000a95fb590 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x00000000a95fb5b0 | [RX] | 0x0401000000000000 0x0010340000000021
0x00000000a95fe9f8 | [TX] | 0x0403000000000101 0x0000000000000021
0x00000000a95feb1c | [TX] | 0x0205000000000000 0x0000000000000021
0x00000000a95ff68c | [RX] | Interrupt
0x00000000a95ff6b4 | [RX] | 0x0405000000000100 0x0020460000000021
0x00000000a95ff6c0 | [RX] | 0x0305000000000000 0x0010560000000021
0x00000000a9600aec | [TX] | 0x0206000000000000 0x0000000000000021
0x00000000a9600b68 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x00000000a9600b90 | [RX] | 0x0306000000000000 0x0010670000000021
0x00000000a960b260 | [TX] | 0x0406000000000100 0x0000000000000021
0x00000000a97c54f4 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x00000000a97c554c | [RX] | 0x0070000000000020 0x0010780000000000
0x00000000a97cad1c | [TX] | 0x00b0000000000020 000000000000000000
0x00000000a97caf00 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x00000000a97caf14 | [RX] | 0x0050000000000000 0x00408c0000000002
0x00000000a97caf1c | [RX] | 0x0050000000000001 0x00309c0000000002
0x00000000a97caf24 | [RX] | 0x0050000000000002 0x0020ac0000000002
0x00000000a97caf2c | [RX] | 0x00b0000000000020 0x0010bc0000000000
0x00000000a97cc8c4 | [TX] | 0x0050000000000000 0x0000000000000002
0x00000000a97cc928 | [TX] | 0x0050000000000001 0x0000000000000002
0x00000000a97cc984 | [TX] | 0x0050000000000002 0x0000000000000002
0x00000000a97d09c0 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x00000000a97d09e4 | [RX] | 0x0050000000000003 0x0010cd0000000002
0x00000000a97d0a90 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x00000000a97d0aa0 | [RX] | 0x0050000000000004 0x0010de0000000002
0x00000000a97d4a6c | [TX] | 0x0050000000000003 0x0000000000000002
0x00000000a97d4af0 | [TX] | 0x0050000000000004 0x0000000000000002
0x00000000aa190d78 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x00000000aa190dd4 | [RX] | 0x0050000000000005 0x0020020000000002
0x00000000aa190df0 | [RX] | 0x0050000000000006 0x0010120000000002
0x00000000aa1917a8 | [TX] | 0x0050000000000005 0x0000000000000002
0x00000000aa191d28 | [TX] | 0x0050000000000006 0x0000000000000002
0x00000001354bfdc4 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x00000001354bfe34 | [RX] | 0x0010400805228000 0x0010010000000001
0x0000000006158bfc | [RX] | 0x0050000000000009 0x00109a0000000002
0x0000000006158c30 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000000006158c3c | [RX] | 0x005000000000000a 0x0010ab0000000002
0x0000000006158ce0 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000000006158ce8 | [RX] | 0x005000000000000b 0x0020bd0000000002
0x0000000006158cf0 | [RX] | 0x005000000000000c 0x0010cd0000000002
0x0000000006158d28 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000000006158d34 | [RX] | 0x005000000000000d 0x0010de0000000002
0x0000000006158e0c | [TX] | 0x0050000000000005 0x0000000000000002
0x0000000006158e70 | [TX] | 0x0050000000000006 0x0000000000000002
0x0000000006158ecc | [TX] | 0x0050000000000007 0x0000000000000002
0x0000000006158f1c | [TX] | 0x0050000000000008 0x0000000000000002
0x0000000006158f74 | [TX] | 0x0050000000000009 0x0000000000000002
0x0000000006158fc0 | [TX] | 0x005000000000000a 0x0000000000000002
0x0000000006159010 | [TX] | 0x005000000000000b 0x0000000000000002
0x0000000006159060 | [TX] | 0x005000000000000c 0x0000000000000002
0x00000000061590b4 | [TX] | 0x005000000000000d 0x0000000000000002
0x000000000615932c | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000000006159340 | [RX] | 0x005000000000000e 0x0010ef0000000002
0x000000000615948c | [TX] | 0x005000000000000e 0x0000000000000002
0x0000000006220da8 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000000006220dbc | [RX] | 0x005000000000000f 0x0030f20000000002
0x0000000006220dc4 | [RX] | 0x0050000000000000 0x0020020000000002
0x0000000006220dc8 | [RX] | 0x0050000000000001 0x0010120000000002
0x0000000006220e30 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000000006220e3c | [RX] | 0x0050000000000002 0x0010230000000002
0x0000000006220ee8 | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000000006220ef4 | [RX] | 0x0050000000000003 0x0010340000000002
0x0000000006220f8c | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000000006220f98 | [RX] | 0x0050000000000004 0x0010450000000002
0x0000000006221040 | [TX] | 0x005000000000000f 0x0000000000000002
0x00000000062210a0 | [TX] | 0x0050000000000000 0x0000000000000002
0x00000000062210f4 | [TX] | 0x0050000000000001 0x0000000000000002
0x0000000006221148 | [TX] | 0x0050000000000002 0x0000000000000002
0x00000000062211a0 | [TX] | 0x0050000000000003 0x0000000000000002
0x00000000062211f8 | [TX] | 0x0050000000000004 0x0000000000000002
0x0000000006af973c | [RX] | Interrupt
0x0000000006af974c | [RX] | 0x0050000000000005 0x0010560000000002
0x0000000006af988c | [TX] | 0x0050000000000005 0x0000000000000002
0x00000000074d40dc | [RX] | Interrupt
0x00000000074d40ec | [RX] | 0x0050000000000006 0x0010670000000002
0x00000000074d423c | [TX] | 0x0050000000000006 0x0000000000000002
0x0000000008ddf668 | [RX] | Interrupt

Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x6
OS release type: User
OS version: 21P365
macOS version: 23A344
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 23.0.0: Thu Aug 17 20:55:28 PDT 2023; root:xnu-10002.1.11~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T8010
KernelCache UUID: 83132AB4798578E2E86BE4877CB66C17
Kernel UUID: 4D383FA8-C2B8-30E0-87FD-74DE482E481E
Boot session UUID: 4EAF4497-8455-4A09-9EA9-8A7DA2520BE2
iBoot version: iBoot-10151.1.1
secure boot?: YES
roots installed: 0
x86 EFI Boot State: 0xd
x86 System State: 0x0
x86 Power State: 0x0
x86 Shutdown Cause: 0xec
x86 Previous Power Transitions: 0x70604000100
PCIeUp link state: 0x89473614
macOS kernel slide: 0x1a800000
Paniclog version: 14
Kernel slide:      0x00000000228a8000
Kernel text base:  0xfffffff0298ac000
mach_absolute_time: 0x13576c784
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x656d9914 0x000b5617
  Sleep   : 0x656d9986 0x000de423
  Wake    : 0x656d9a3d 0x000ca3e0
  Calendar: 0x656d9a9f 0x000bf3dd

Zone info:
  Zone map: 0xffffffddc5688000 - 0xffffffe3c5688000
  . VM    : 0xffffffddc5688000 - 0xffffffdeabcec000
  . RO    : 0xffffffdeabcec000 - 0xffffffdef89b8000
  . GEN0  : 0xffffffdef89b8000 - 0xffffffdfdf01c000
  . GEN1  : 0xffffffdfdf01c000 - 0xffffffe0c5680000
  . GEN2  : 0xffffffe0c5680000 - 0xffffffe1abce8000
  . GEN3  : 0xffffffe1abce8000 - 0xffffffe292350000
  . DATA  : 0xffffffe292350000 - 0xffffffe3c5688000
  Metadata: 0xffffffe3c5698000 - 0xffffffe3c6e98000
  Bitmaps : 0xffffffe3c6e98000 - 0xffffffe3c6fc4000
  Extra   : 0 - 0

TPIDRx_ELy = {1: 0xffffffe0c5990388  0: 0x0000000000000001  0ro: 0x0000000000000000 }
CORE 0: PC=0xfffffff029ffe040, LR=0xfffffff029ffdeb8, FP=0xffffffe3e8b4fc10
CORE 1 is the one that panicked. Check the full backtrace for details.
Compressor Info: 0% of compressed pages limit (OK) and 0% of segments limit (OK) with 0 swapfiles and OK swap space
Panicked task 0xffffffe0c56245d0: 0 pages, 243 threads: pid 0: kernel_task
Panicked thread: 0xffffffe0c5990388, backtrace: 0xffffffe3e8993800, tid: 420
          lr: 0xfffffff029aa2fe0  fp: 0xffffffe3e8993870
          lr: 0xfffffff029bd06ec  fp: 0xffffffe3e89938e0
          lr: 0xfffffff029bcf5f4  fp: 0xffffffe3e8993a00
          lr: 0xfffffff029a65628  fp: 0xffffffe3e8993a10
          lr: 0xfffffff029aa2a1c  fp: 0xffffffe3e8993dc0
          lr: 0xfffffff02a120fc8  fp: 0xffffffe3e8993de0
          lr: 0xfffffff0289d03e0  fp: 0xffffffe3e8993e70
          lr: 0xfffffff0289a8b18  fp: 0xffffffe3e8993ea0
          lr: 0xfffffff02a06b72c  fp: 0xffffffe3e8993ee0
          lr: 0xfffffff02a06af9c  fp: 0xffffffe3e8993f20
```

Please does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: First suggestion would be update to the latest OS version, Darwin 23.0.0 was the initial release, there have been three bug-fix updates since.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have updated to the latest OS and it hasn't restarted since then...will observe for now. Thank you very much!